# what registry to change to force app to run in second monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-registry, windows-10

I have two monitors and I want to make sure that some applications (I did not make myself) will run in second monitor, what registry key should I change for that ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe this is a registry option.  Most apps open first on the primary monitor.  Others will remember their position from last use. But if the app doesn't implement it, you may ne stuck.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to launch the app and move it to the secondary monitor.

Comment: thanks but this wont work for me, I need to force the application to open in the 2nd monitor.